# Angular-cli getting error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, web

I'm new to Angular 2 and trying to start the development. I have installed the npm (3.10.10) and Anugular-cli (1.0.0-beta.28.3), node (v6.9.5). I created the new project with **ng new begin** (begin is the name of the new project). Now I am trying to build or start the server an getting the error (with verbose):

```
PS E:\#Angular2\001_begin\begin> ng build --verbose
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"

...
...

Hash: 548903fff1e2f098f7d9
Version: webpack 2.2.0
Time: 16219ms
               Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
 polyfills.bundle.js   254 kB    0, 4  polyfills
      main.bundle.js  6.53 kB    1, 4  main
    styles.bundle.js  10.3 kB    2, 4  styles
    vendor.bundle.js  2.88 MB    3, 4  vendor
    inline.bundle.js  5.76 kB       4  inline
polyfills.bundle.map   318 kB    0, 4  polyfills
     main.bundle.map  3.54 kB    1, 4  main
   styles.bundle.map  13.9 kB    2, 4  styles
   vendor.bundle.map  3.08 MB    3, 4  vendor
   inline.bundle.map  5.82 kB       4  inline
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.map (polyfills) 228 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.map (main) 4.01 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.map (styles) 10 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.map (vendor) 2.38 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in Could not resolve "E:/" from "E:/".
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  2.88 kB       0
chunk    {0} index.html 339 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

Anyone has seen it? I was digging into the google results but... without result ;/

Regards.

Comment: I just wonder if you could delete this hash sign `#` from the directory.

Comment: My HERO! Removed the '#' and it works! BTW how uncomfortable is to deal with such errors when you want to start just programming.

Comment: That's great to hear! :) Btw, if I would make a full reply, would you accept it?

Comment: Sure :) you answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the hash sign `#` from the project's directory :)